# como configurar o driver para usar com o selenium

Tags: python

como eu consigo usar o selenium com o driver? eu estou querendo aprender automação web já faz um tempinho, porém eu queria saber como configurar o driver para que o selenium use ele,sendo que no meu script ele abre o navegador e em seguida fecha.Eu estou utilizando windows 11 com a versão do google chrome 119.0.6045.124

Comment: Boas-vindas ao site. Por favor, não [duplique perguntas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/588745/3635), para corrigir os problemas de uma pergunta fechada você deve edita-la, e não duplica-la, após editar, se a edição tiver corrigido os problemas 5 usuários irão avaliar a pergunta para uma possível reabertura. Comentários devem ser feitos na pergunta original.

Answer (score -3):

Opa eu recomendo que use o **webdriver-manager** pois ele sempre vai usar o driver mais atualizado.

se estiver usando pip

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

Exemplo de código com Chrome:

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver

service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
```

outra dica fundamental é rodar o script em modo iterativo para que vc consiga ir manipulando o código, para isso execute:

```
python -i script.py
```

vc também pode usar o ipython se quiser um ambiente mais moderno

```
ipython -i script.py
```